# Raise ArgumentError if creating class object parameter hash did not met requirments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, parameters

i have little problem i can't solve. I have Class to which is passed hash with parameters, but i have to raise and error if the parameter count is less or more than 2 and if any of the values are nill.

What could be the best practise here, if i dont want to pass separate parameters, but a hash?

Class:

```
Class MyClass
  attr_accessor :param1, :param2

  def initialize(attr_hash)

    self.param1 = attr_hash[:param1].to_f
    self.param2 = attr_hash[:param2]

  end
end
```

and i am passing something like this

```
instance = MyClass.new({param1: 12, param2: "Ok"})
```

Is there a raily or more ruby way to achieve what i want, not iterating trough hash and checking if any of the values are empty and if count is less or more than 2?

Answer (score 2):

Don't raise an error if parameter is invalid. Instead, create `valid?` instance method to check the state.

Also, use Ruby [OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) class if you would like to pass hash as input.

```
require 'ostruct'

class MyClass < OpenStruct

  def valid?
    @table.length > 1    
  end

end

a = MyClass.new(a: :b, c: :d)
a.valid? # true
a.c # :d

a=MyClass.new(a: :b)
a.valid? # false
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
def initialize(hash)
  raise 'error' if hash.size < 2 or hash.value?(nil)
  self.param1 = hash[:param1].to_f
  self.param2 = hash[:param2]
end
```

As [blelump](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2458753/blelump) pointed out this would the better way of creating your class:

```
require 'ostruct'

class MyClass < OpenStruct

  def valid?
    @table.length > 1 and !@table.value?(nil)   
  end

end
```